# Solidity - Error : cannot unmarshal hex string of odd length into Go value of type common

Tags: solidity, contract-development

I have a contract where some calculations are done and ether has to be transfered.

**js file**

```
 for(i=0;i<l;i++){  //'l' represents count of addresses to which ether has to be transfered.

 bal(a,b,c);

    }

function bal(a,b,c){

  Balcontract.deployed().then(function(instance){

    var registerInstance = instance;
    return registerInstance.InReturn(a,b,c,{from: iswallet,gas: 4000000,value:web3.toWei(0.006,'ether')});

    });
    }
```

**contract file**

```
 uint256 bal;

 function InReturn(uint256 a,uint256 b,uint256 c) public payable { 

   // iwallet holds the address

   //bal = (1000*5300*10^14)/1000; Need to send 0.53 ether
    bal = (a*c*100000000000000)/b;

    iwallet.transfer(bal);


}
```

But contract is reverted with error :

> Error: invalid argument 0: json: cannot unmarshal hex string of odd
>   length into Go value of type common

When I tried

> bal = (1000*5300*10^12)/1000;  //0.0053 ether was transfered

Even `inwallet.transfer(530000000000000000); //53 * 10^16` is showing error.

Thanks in advance.Help will be appreciated :)

Comment: This is not a solidity error. You need to post more information about how you are calling this contract.

Comment: I tried in ropsten..Still not working